# Recursive bubble sort in X-Y coordinate in C

Tags: c

I would like to sort the elements associated with X

The method tried not in a recursive way, any idea how to do it

The expected output is:
{5,73} , {11,19}, {11,34}, {11,68}, {13,5}

I have tried this so far, but only X is sorted while Y remain in original position

```
void sort(struct Points a[], int n)
        {

            if (n == 1) return;

            for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
                if (a[i].X > a[i+1].X)
                    swap(&a[i].X, &a[i+1].X);

            //sort(&a[0], n);

        }
    struct Points {
        int X, Y;
    };

    void swap(int *a, int *b)
    {
        int t;

        t  = *b;
        *b = *a;
        *a = t;
    }


        void sort(struct Points a[], int n);

        int main()
        {
            int i;
            struct Points ptArray[5] = { {11, 34}, {5, 73}, {11, 19}, {13, 5}, {11,
                68}};

            sort(ptArray, 5);


            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                printf("(%d, %d)\n", ptArray[i].X, ptArray[i].Y);
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `swap(&a[i].X, &a[i+1].X)` -> `swap(&a[i], &a[i+1])` if the rest is correct

Comment: As @Federico wrote, your `swap` function should likely have a different signature, i.e. `void swap(struct Points *a, struct Points *b)`. Also, struct name should be `Point`, not `Points`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

[1] you want to swap `Points` object so modified `swap` function looks

```
void swap(Points *a, Points *b)
{
    Points t;

    t  = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = t;
}
```

[2] now you are sorting elements only by checking `X` coordinates, you don't have condition to check Y - values

[3] when you want to call `sort` function recursively, `n` parameter must be decremented before calling function

`sort` function should be

```
void sort(struct Points a[], int n)
{    
  if (n > 1)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        if (a[i].X > a[i+1].X || (a[i].X == a[i+1].X && a[i].Y > a[i+1].Y))
            swap(&a[i], &a[i+1]);
    sort (a,--n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

full working code -

```
struct point{
    int x; int y;
};

bool isGreater(point p1, point p2){
    if(p1.x>p2.x) return true;
        else if(p1.x==p2.x){
            return p1.y>p2.y;
        }
    return false;
}

void recBubble(point *arr, int n){
    if (n == 1) return;

    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        if (isGreater(arr[i],arr[i+1]))
            swap(arr[i], arr[i+1]);
    recBubble(arr, n-1);
}
```